# convert Jquery to simple javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

thanks for your help in advance.

Can anyone help me convert the following Jquery to javascript

```js
    <!--script-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.nav-btn').click(function(){
                $('.dropdown').slideToggle();
            });
        });
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.nk-popup').delay(5000).fadeIn();
            $("html, body").delay(5400).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        });
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.popup-open-btn').click(function(){
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                $('.nk-popup').fadeIn();
            });
        });
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.fa-times-circle').click(function(){
                $('.nk-popup').fadeOut();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!--/script-->
```

The only reason i am not able to use the above code is it use code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js "The jquery library" i want to remove this link because it is causing other conflicts. I will be very thankful if someone convert it to simple javascript.

Comment: what conflict error you are getting ?

Comment: There's another plugin which i am using on my wordpress website, when i use the above code the plugin stop working.

Comment: Kumkanillam, is there any way tool which i can use to convert it simple javascript.

Comment: All animation is tricky with plain JS. You are looking for CSS Transitions. The above code can use much lower than latest jQuery - if the other plugin is using jQuery remove the `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and use whatever the other is using

Comment: mplungjan, will it work if i use the same one for both, i mean if i use the one which is used by the plugin?

Comment: @Abbas Yes it will work. put @ before user name to notify them

Comment: @mplungjan I have tried but didn't worked. Can you please guide me how i can copy the part of library which is controlling the above code. I will use that in <Script> tags, it will work. I have tried copying the whole file and pasting it inside my file, it works but still the same problem. What i am looking for is to copy a part of the library for for the above code.

Comment: Without seeing the code for both I cannot help. Make sure one and only one jQuery is loaded in the head of the page and nowhere else (view source) Also post console errors

Comment: It could be that the plugin is loading jQuery (or something else) as $, causing the conflict. On the page with the plugin, without loading your code, try typing `$` in the console, and then `jQuery` and post the results.